# Does the BUSY flag work for the Clock Control Registers?

Tags: software-development, audio

The docs suggest that certain registers shouldn't be messed with if the BUSY flag is set. I've tried disabling the General Purpose clocks, but the busy flag is always set.

See page 107 of the BCM2835 Peripherals document.

Comment: I think you're finding a niche in our current user knowledge-base.

Comment: When I get an answer I'll record it here.